# Select statement with in ISNULL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, isnull

I am writing a stored procedure and within this procedure I am using isNULL. If the value is null I want to use a select statement as the replacement value is this even possible?

```
IF ISNULL(@v_FilePrefix, (SELECT @v_FilePrefix = TransactionTypePrefix 
                            FROM [ConfigTransactionType] 
                           WHERE TransactionTypeID = @TransactionTypeID));
```

Comment: no, its not possible. where does @v_FilePrefix come from before the above code? you should improve the logic to cater for the null value in the original query.

Comment: I went with your approach and it worked exactly as intended.This is what I ended up using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
IF @v_FilePrefix IS NULL
BEGIN

    SELECT @v_FilePrefix = TransactionTypePrefix
    FROM [ConfigTransactionType]
    WHERE TransactionTypeID = @TransactionTypeID

END
```

I think this is what you're after?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the @TransactionTypeID will always return a value:

```
SELECT @v_FilePrefix = COALESCE(@v_FilePrefix, TransactionTypePrefix)
  FROM [ConfigTransactionType] 
 WHERE TransactionTypeID = @TransactionTypeID
```

COALESCE will return the first non-null value.  If @v_FilePrefix is not null, it will just set the value to itself.

But it would be best to use:

```
IF @v_FilePrefix IS NULL
BEGIN

   SELECT @v_FilePrefix = TransactionTypePrefix
     FROM [ConfigTransactionType]
    WHERE TransactionTypeID = @TransactionTypeID

END
```